# Im having problems with Typescript configuration to C# asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript-typings

I added a TS file, named 'boot.ts' and I'm having an error in its line 3.
Error : "Cannot find modul './app'" - boot.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I already installed Typepings in my Nuget Packages

Also added this to my .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: And you have that module?

Comment: Please provide some details on your file and directory structure as these errors are often related to files being in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to path is not declared properly.check the path

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your app.ts and boot.ts are in the same folder. Otherwise you'll need to provide the proper path.